# ngix and php5-fpm blank page

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

iam trying to include php5-fpm into my nginx. but i only get an blank page. And i dont really know why. i installed ngix-portable (https://github.com/moezzie/nginx-portable/blob/master/README.md) and my config file is:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

The PHP5-FPM listens on port 9000 i can open with telnet a port. Where is my error :(?

Comment: What does the (error)log shows?

Comment: no entry is written in the error log :(

Comment: also no entries in the connection log? And if yes what status codes do they have?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2013:14:51:49 +0200] "GET /server.php HTTP/1.1" 404 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2013:15:26:38 +0200] "GET /server.php HTTP/1.1" 404 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"

Comment: I spy 404: "page not found". So the empty page is because it is not found.

Comment: Do you have entries in the PHP error log? Can you make a direct request to 127.0.0.1:9000/index.php?

Comment: so the  "fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;" must be wrong? if i try to connect to the 127.0.0.1:9000/index.php over the browser i get an "connection reseted"

Comment: I think the problem is in FastCGI. Not in nginx.

Comment: Aug 07 12:41:58.389890 [NOTICE] fpm is running, pid 15860
Aug 07 12:41:58.401406 [NOTICE] ready to handle connections
in the php5-fpm log. the php5 log is empty

Comment: Please update your question with configurations for PHP-FPM and the pool.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen inconsistent implementation between `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `SCRIPT_NAME` params, so I define them both like this:

```
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
```