# LEMP - Magento displays blank page

Tags: php, linux, magento, nginx, magento2

Trying to setup [Magento2](https://github.com/magento/magento2) on my LEMP stack. Was following the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) (did that after [compiling from sources](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.nginx.php) for multiple time since it was hard to fulfill composer requirements for Magento2)

- Installed composer
- Configured and run `php`, `php-fpm`
- Did some trivial tests (success)

However, a blank screen is all I get. The `nginx` configuration

```
server {
    listen   2000;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2;
    index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

The permission set is to `-R 777` (test purpose only), `user` and `group` is `www-data`. Was able to run `.php` scripts, problem applies to Magento2.

Read also some related issues (without any positive results) :

- [Nginx configuration with Magento 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353341/nginx-configuration-with-magento-1-8)
- [ngix and php5-fpm blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103966/ngix-and-php5-fpm-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

The above query is incomplete the nginx configuration.
Please use the below link configuration of nginx.

http://gotechnies.com/magento2-lemp-nginx-ubuntu/

Comment: Answers should not be limited to "read this link" but should at least provide essentials parts of the link to help solve the problem.. links will die sooner or later.